# Tensorflow: Aborted configuration when building from source

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, gpu, configure, bazel

I am trying to build Tensorflow from source on a Centos6 machine (with GPU support - Titanx). I first built bazel from source. The Tensorflow configuration halted with the following message:
WARNING: Output base '/uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/hpcapps/.cache/bazel/_bazel_hpcapps/9e108560974a04e4bdc017d0599ed450' is on NFS. This may lead to surprising failures and undetermined behavior.
Extracting Bazel installation...
..............
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --expunge_async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
ERROR: /uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/hpcapps/.cache/bazel/_bazel_hpcapps/9e108560974a04e4bdc017d0599ed450/server (Directory not empty).

Notice that the I emptied the .cache/bazel directory before starting the ./configure.
Any idea what may have gone wrong?
Thanks,

Wim

Comment: Note the warning: building on an NFS directory is not supported.

Comment: Thank you. I have set the env. variable TEST_TMPDIR to TEST_TMPDIR= /scratch/local/hpcapps/bazel (local scratch space) and it resolved the issue.